# Mockito calls stubbed method even if using doReturn

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing

I want to create an integration test where a put method is called on a controller and it updates a certain object. During this process, a service class is involved which calls a third party API to do some stuff. In my case, I want to stub the service method which is involved in calling the third party as it is not the point to test the third party.

Having that said, I will present my code and I wait for an answer about why this does not work as expected and/or any other workaround.

This is my service class in which is the method call I want to stub.

```
public class ProjectService implements SomeInterfance {

// the third party service
private final DamConnector damConnector;
// some other fields

    public ProjectDTO save(ProjectDTO projectDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Project : {}", projectDTO);
        // some operations
        synchronizeWithDamAndSave(project, parentChanging); //this is the method call I want to be skiped
        //other operations
        return projectMapper.toDto(project, this);
    }

    //the method that I want to stub
    public Asset synchronizeWithDamAndSave(Project project, boolean includeDocuments) {
        Asset asset = synchronizeWithDam(project, includeDocuments);
        projectRepository.save(project);
        return asset;
    }

}
```

And my integration test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SppApp.class)
public class ProjectResourceIT {

//other fields

//my service use autowire as it needs to make the service calls
@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

//this is my setup method where I create the spy of project service and define the doReturn behavior when my method is called
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    ProjectService spyProjectService = Mockito.spy(projectService);
    Mockito.doReturn(new Asset()).when(spyProjectService).synchronizeWithDamAndSave(Mockito.any(Project.class),Mockito.anyBoolean());
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


    final ProjectResource projectResource = new ProjectResource(spyProjectService, clientService, securityService);
    this.restProjectMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(projectResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
        .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
        .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
        .setValidator(validator).build();
    }

}
...

public void updateProject() throws Exception {
    // initialization of the test

    // this is where I call my controller
    restProjectMockMvc.perform(put("/api/projects")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(projectDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

The problem in my case is that mockito enters in **synchronizeWithDamAndSave** method just after

*Mockito.doReturn(new Asset()).when(spyProjectService).synchronizeWithDamAndSave(Mockito.any(Project.class),Mockito.anyBoolean());*

this line is called, before the method to be called from the rest api.

What should I do? Any hints about why this is happening?

Comment: Mockito.spy is wrapping the instance, it will still call the implementation (unless overriden). You might mean to use Mockito.mock?

Comment: I know that will call the implementation, that's why I overriten it with mockito doReturn...when. Isn't this the role of this method? @Jayr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot's proxies are not working wit Mockito. Use [@SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) instead of @Autowired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you are right, mockito can't work with proxies so SpyBean was the solution

Comment: Sorry Oncioiu you are right, @rmunge's must be the correct answer